# Reordering pivot table headers

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have the output to a pivot table which looks as follows

[image]

I would like the output to be reordered as shown below

[image]

Having looked at other similar posts, it's some kind of post processing on the pivot table.
I have tried `pd.swap_levels(0, 1, axis=1)` but it does not give the correct results. Note I also want to reverse the order of the weeks  so that it becomes 4 to 1.

Can anyone help with the required syntax to get the desired outcome?

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341); post the text itself and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code) or [table formatting](/editing-help#tables).

Comment: FWIW, from a glance, it looks like you just need [`.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)

Comment: Maybe this is just a typo, but `pd.swap_levels` doesn't exist. You mean [`pd.DataFrame.swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html), right?

Comment: It'd also help to provide a [reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341), meaning example data and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `swaplevel` then `sort_index` in descending order but use `sort_remaining=False` to maintain the other level order:

```
# Output
>>> df.swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, level=0, ascending=False, sort_remaining=False)

Weeknum    4            3            2            1        
        Late Neg Pos Late Neg Pos Late Neg Pos Late Neg Pos
0          D   H   L    C   G   K    B   F   J    A   E   I

# Input
>>> df
        Late          Neg          Pos         
Weeknum    1  2  3  4   1  2  3  4   1  2  3  4
0          A  B  C  D   E  F  G  H   I  J  K  L
```